# An issue when summing a column in R

Tags: r

For the following data:

```
Step    isWeekOfYearVisible setDecorationBackgroundVisible  setAlwaysFireDayProperty    setFont
1       0                   1                               0                           4
2       0                   1                               0                           4
3       0                   1                               0                           4
4       0                   1                               0                           4
5       0                   1                               0                           4
6       0                   1                               0                           4
7       0                   1                               0                           4
8       0                   1                               0                           4
```

I would like to sum the values of a column using a column name. For that, I wrote the following R script:

```
  ddd <- read.csv("/home/adam/Desktop/data.csv")
  Method_name <- "isWeekOfYearVisible"
  col <- ddd[[Method_name]]
  print(sum(as.numeric(col)))
```

The result of this is 8 which is wrong as the sum of of the values of this column should be 0.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

That is mostly because `isWeekOfYearVisible` column is a `factor`, safely convert it to numeric and then `sum`. Use

```
sum(as.numeric(as.character(ddd[[Method_name]])))
```

For example, for this data

```
ddd <- structure(list(Step = 1:8, isWeekOfYearVisible = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "0", class = "factor"), 
setDecorationBackgroundVisible = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L), setAlwaysFireDayProperty = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L), setFont = c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-8L), class = "data.frame")
```

when you do

```
sum(as.numeric(ddd[[Method_name]]))
#[1] 8
```

Then when you convert it into character and then numeric you get

```
sum(as.numeric(as.character(ddd[[Method_name]])))
#[1] 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Exactly what @RonakShah said, this is probably due to you having the strings as factors.

Besides his solution, you can just set `options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`, for the `data.frames` not to convert strings to factors.

Another possibility is for you to use [`tidyverse`](https://www.tidyverse.org/), and load the csv with [`read_csv`](https://readr.tidyverse.org/reference/read_delim.html), and work the data with [`tibble`](https://tibble.tidyverse.org/), which is a modern implementation of data.frames. This implementation removes some weird behaviors like this one, and some others.

Here is an example of what I just talked:

```
# Your use case
df = data.frame(list( "a" = as.character(rep(0, 10)) ))
sum( as.numeric( df[["a"]] ) )
# [1] 10

# Converting your factors back to string, by getting the respective factor level
df = data.frame(list( "a" = as.character(rep(0, 10)) ))
sum( as.numeric( levels(df[["a"]]) ) )
# [1] 0

# The same thing just using tibble from tidyverse
library(tidyverse)
df = tibble(list( "a" = as.character(rep(0, 10)) ))
sum( as.numeric( df[["a"]] ) )
# [1] 0

# Setting the global setting for not to convert strings to factors
options(stringsAsFactors = F)
df = data.frame(list("a"=as.character(rep(0, 10)), "b"=as.character(rep(1, 10))))
sum( as.numeric( df[["a"]] ) )
# [1] 0
```